# How do I make it so the user can log out of the website?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

On my site the user has the option to register and then log in but i am wondering how would i make it so the user can log out after.

c# code: Here is the code for the login.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_Fail.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            // connecion to the database
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Fasthosts_MMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fasthosts_Registration_MM WHERE username='" + tb_UsernameLogin.Text + "' AND password='" + tb_PasswordLogin.Text + "'", conn);
            /* in above line the program is selecting the whole data from table and the matching it with the user name and password provided by user. */
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //this is creating a virtual table  
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {

                Response.Redirect("Domains.aspx");

            }
            else
            {
                lb_Fail.Text = ("Incorrect login details");
                lb_Fail.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

What code would I need for the log out button if created one.

Comment: Off-topic:  You need to read up on [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), and fix your code accordingly.

Comment: and dont store password in pure text. salt and hash them please

Comment: Don't worry i wont be releasing this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting ahead of yourself. You haven't actually logged them in yet. :) All you've done is verified their credentials are correct.

There is an example of Forms Authentication [here](https://www.splinter.com.au/aspnet-forms-authentication-to-your-own-datab/). There are three important parts:

1. The web.config that tells IIS you are using Forms Authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

2. The login (specifically `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()`, which indicates a successful login)
3. The logout:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
```

And yes, fix your SQL injection problems if you plan on releasing this on the internet. You can find help with that [here](http://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet) (basically, use parameters rather than putting text from the user into your SQL command).

Comment: I'm not going to be releasing this website it's just for school.:)

Comment: @Marks_The_God Even if it's just for school, you need to learn to do things the secure way instead of the insecure way. Are you learning this because you want a degree, or are you learning this because you want to be an effective employee at your future workplace?

Comment: Both. : : : : : : :